# Self-referencing ManyToMany-relationship not updating

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I modeled a unidirectional @ManyToMany self-referencing relationship. A test may require other tests in order to be executed:

```java
@Entity
public class Test{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
      name = "required_",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "test_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "required_test_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  )
  private Set<Test> requiredTests;

}
```

Each test is described by an XML-file.
In the XML the required tests are referenced by name.

Now i'm trying to import all the tests, but so far the dependency-relationships between the tests are not correctly saved in the DB. I guess I'm doing something wrong.

This is what I did (pseudo-code):

```
//Each test is imported with this method:
private void import(TestCaseXml testCaseXml) {

Test test= testRepository.findByName(testCaseXml.getName()).orElse(new Test());

test.setRequiredTests(fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn(testCaseXml));
testRepository.save(test);

}

private Set<Test> fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn(
      final TestCaseXml testCaseXml) {

   
final List<String> requiredTestcasesByName = testCaseXml.getNameOfRequiredTests();

return requiredTestcasesByName.stream()
    .map(name -> testRepository.findByName(name)
    .orElse(testRepository.save(new Test().setName(name))))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

// The import of all the tests is packed in one single transaction.
```

So far, as result: only one dependency is persisted (let's say Test A requires B, C and D), then the joint table would look like ( A - D ).

Does anyone would have a clue?

---

**Edit after Chris' feedback**

I made some more experiments, I'd like to share here since the outcome is really confusing.

First scenario: Let's say I have 3 tests I want to import (A, B and C) and they will be processed in this order.

- Test A requires Test B and Test C.
- Test B and C have no requirement.

When Test A is being imported, at some point fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn() will be called. I debugged it and can confirm that the method returns a Set containing Test B and Test C, both of them with name and id (The presence of the id is a bit surprising - may be Hibernate flushed before the end of the global transaction?). Anyway, this result do not confirm Chris' hypothesis, since it does return a Set with the 2 expected tests.

Nevertheless: I repeated this first scenario, but this time using List instead of Set, as Chris suggested, and indeed it did work. To be honest, I don't understand why.

Now it gets still a bit more weird:
Second scenario:  I have 3 tests I want to import (A, B and C) and they will be processed in this order.

- Test A has no requirement
- Test B requires Test A and C
- Test C has no requirement
  This will throw an Exception

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: (conn=819) Duplicate entry 'Test A' for key 'XYZ'
```

Somehow it seems I fixed this by getting rid of the functional syntax in fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn()

I replaced

```
return requiredTestcasesByName.stream()
    .map(name -> testRepository.findByName(name)
    .orElse(testRepository.save(new Test().setName(name))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with this:

```
final var requiredTests = new ArrayList<Test>();

for (final String name: requiredTestcasesByName) {
     final Test test = testRepository.findByName(testcaseName).isPresent()
          ? testRepository.findByName(name).get()
          : testRepository.save(new Test().setName(name));
      requiredTests.add(test);
    }
    return requiredTests;
```

After performing these 2 changes (List instead of Set, and get rid of the functional syntax) it seems to work as expected. I'd like to understand what is happening behind the scene.

---

Edit 27.06.22
I setup a demo project to reproduce this strange behaviour:
https://github.com/JulienDeBerlin/manyToMany/tree/master

Comment: What is fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn(testCaseXml) returning? If it is a Set of existing tests read in from (or saved through) a repository, what is the transaction scope of the method you are running this code in? Ie is this all running in a single transaction scope that just isn't committing or being rolled back? Are new tests in that fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn logic being saved or is it just the ManyToMany reference that isn't?

Comment: fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn looks in the persistence context if the required tests are available there and if not create a new tests and place them in the persistence context. The all process of test-import (incl. fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn for each test) happens in one single transaction.

Comment: Again, what is in the 'set' returned from fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn? You will need to debug it, but java.util.set has logic that might be the problem. Try using List instead as I bet it'll fix the issue. Set prevents duplicates which is based on equals checks. It seems a common pattern to put in equals and hashcode implementations that are incorrect into entities without understanding how they affect Sets and maps, and chances are yours are based on an ID that isn't generated right away, so is null. I'd bet they all 'equal' each other, so replace each other.

Comment: Let's say I have 3 tests I want to import (A, B and C).

Comment: Not sure the point of your comment. Did you use a debugger and check what is referenced in the set returned from fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn? I don't think it contains your tests (B, C, D) that you expect and that it ONLY contains test D. Try using a list instead of Set, and verify your entities that they don't have equals/hashcode method implementations - remove them if they do. I don't understand why everyone feels they need equals/hashcode implementations in their entities, but if they aren't done right, they muck up Set and map functionality.

Comment: There are way too many possibilities with new/existing, so you should narrow it down exactly and focus on one. In your experiments, you removed D from the file. In the new A->[B,C] setup, are all entirely new? Assuming yes, what exactly gets put in the DB when using a set? For the 'new' constraint issue; break it down into the specific sequence called as we cannot tell if 'findByName' is called or save is - I would guess that Save is always called in the new scenario, causing an insert of what will be duplicate A data; you should be able to tell what the constraint and the 'XYZ' is

Comment: I have no idea why your new code works at all. What is testcaseName exactly, and what does the find return? It seems like it forces either save(new Test) for both A and C (which should be a problem if A exist already) or findByName for both, which shouldn't return anything for C. if it is a typo and testcaseName==name, then it looks like it should operate the same as the original code and likely to some nuance in how Spring handles optionals

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident you have implemented equals and hashcode methods in your entity classes, and that they rely on the ID. Your code can then be broken into the following equivalent sequence:

```
Set set = new HashSet();
Test b = new Test().setName(b);
set.add(b);
Test c = new Test().setName(c);
set.add(c);
Test d = new Test().setName(d);
set.add(d);

assertEquals(set.size(),1);
```

Why? If you check what is returned from each testRepository.save call, they do not have their IDs generated. JPA does NOT guarantee sequences are set on persist calls (which are underneath your Spring repository.save call), but does guarantee they will be set on the instance when the transaction is synchronized (flushed or committed) to the database. As they are all in the same transaction, that only happens AFTER they are added to the set. Your hashcode/equality methods have already dealt with all 3 and determined they are the same instance (null id), so replaces the existing one with the latest one added.

Simplest solution is to return a list instead:

```
private List<Test> fetchAlreadyExistentOrCreateRequiredTestsDeclaredIn(
      final TestCaseXml testCaseXml) {

   
final List<String> requiredTestcasesByName = testCaseXml.getNameOfRequiredTests();

return requiredTestcasesByName.stream()
    .map(name -> testRepository.findByName(name)
    .orElse(testRepository.save(new Test().setName(name))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I'd also suggest fixing or just outright removing your Equals/hashcode methods from your entities, betting you don't really need them.

Comment: Hi Chris, I get your point and you're right that using List instead of Set helps, but I don't think it did work for the reasons you're assuming. See the edit part in my question.

Comment: You can debug what I've said by putting breakpoints in your entities hash/equals method and see where/when they get called, but I still recommend you outright remove them from the problem. Your new problem is something else and might need a new question to break out exactly what is happening to get more traction and not get confused with the original setup/problem

Comment: I looked i the hibernate logs and for some reason, Hibernate deletes more than it should. If you want to have a look on it, I setup a small demo-rpoject to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/JulienDeBerlin/manyToMany/tree/master

Comment: I mentioned a few times your issues revolve around equals/hashcode implementations, and Lombok creates those methods comparing ALL your attributes with the @Data annotation. That messes up Set immensely and is just bad practice in general. Removing that solves your initial question, so please form a new one on the new issues so this one can help others. As for deleting more than it should; what do you mean? Show the log somewhere, but I don't understand how a deleteAll can delete more than it should. Is it when it is run? It is all in the same transaction, so it depends the spring impl.